# apache mod_rewrite variable hostnames with one redirect?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I have a test server (webtest.example.com) and a live server (www.example.com).

I also have example.org, example.net, etc. I want those to redirect to example.com. I also want any non-www entries to redirect to www.

Basically, I just want to know if there is a more efficient (i.e. fewer lines) way to handle this?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^webtest\.example
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^webtest\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^webtest\.example
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://webtest.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

..it seems like maybe there would be a way to combine the 2 blocks into one block..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with rules that do what you want and then combine them. In the question you have 3 requirements and rules which only cover two of them - there's one rule missing.

A key tip is to write rules that use a positive match (starts with foo) and not a negative match (starts with anything except foo) as otherwise exclusions are required and should you add to your ruleset in the future - things easily break.

### Redirect example.notcom to www.example.com

[There are many examples](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache/blob/master/src/rewrites/rewrite_www.conf#L37-L44) for this, in this particular case:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

It doesn't matter whether it's `example.com`, `example.net` or `example.org` - they all start with example - match no-www domain requests and redirect to `www.example.com`

### Redirect www.example.notcom to www.example.com

For this, use a negative lookahead to exclude `www.example.com`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.(?!com)$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I.e. match any host starting with www.example, that doesn't end with .com

### Redirect webtest.example.notcom to webtest.example.com

Similarly, using a negative lookahead this can be normalized:

```
# capture the subdomain, and match hosts that don't end with .com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^webtest\.example\.(?!com)
RewriteRule ^ http://webtest.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I.e. match any host starting with webtest.example, that doesn't end with .com

### Can the rules be combined?

The ones on a subdomain can be:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www|webtest)\.example\.(?!com)
RewriteRule ^ http://%1.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The first one however, can't easily be included here (at least, I can't think of a trivial way to do so).

### All together:

The end result is therefore:

```
# Redirect no-www requests to www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Redirect requests on the wrong tld to .com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www|webtest)\.example\.(?!com)
RewriteRule ^ http://%1.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Ah @AD7six , I just realized something: my question has an error. The 2nd line on the first block is incorrect. On that line, I was intending to match "any (non webtest) 'example' domain, with or without www". Which might actually take 2 additional lines RewriteCond lines..... In other words, I would want, for example, www.example.org AND example.org to redirect to www.example.com. I can edit my question, but then you will need to edit your answer. Does that sound like a plan?.. or maybe you could just edit both of them yourself??.. lol idk

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: thanks a lot. No pressure, but I would like to use your code in my project without attribution, if you will allow that..?

Comment: ..on second thought, I removed my "accept" b/c your 2nd block does not seem to work correctly for some reason.. ?

Comment: reason = negative-lookahead is a zero-width match - removed the $ from the regexes - [What you can expect](https://gist.github.com/AD7six/b2a513b8fae3e04e7220). Only accept an answer **after** testing it's correct =). "user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required" though I don't think anyone is going to care for a couple of rewrite rules.

Comment: Haha, thanks! Yes, that is precisely why I ask -- so that I can bypass the attribution. I believe that you own the copyright/rights to the code and can allow others to bypass attribution if you wish. Regardless, thanks for the help here! I have restored your big green checkmark :)

Comment: I do not, just as you don't own the question - the site does.

Comment: I respectfully disagree with you. I believe the site effectively licenses your contributions based on your consent (i.e. usage of the site). While defining ownership of something like "code" may be somewhat convoluted, I believe we can be safe in saying that we, as the original authors, retain ownership/copyright. But this discussion may not be appropriate for this comment area. Feel free to delete if you would like. I have a question on the topic here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253618/if-i-use-so-code-on-my-website-how-should-i-give-attribution

Comment: [Attribution required](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) - "If you republish this content, we **require** that you". Attribution is not optional, and I am not "we"; "we" is stack exchange. But for the sake of a conclusion no, I do not allow you to bypass attribution =).